# Walmart MWS API not returning nextCursor

Tags: node.js, api, walmart-api

After checking the [Walmart Markeptlace API to retrieve all the items](https://developer.walmart.com/api/us/mp/items#operation/getAllItems) in the catalog, you can see that it will return:

- errors (array of objects)
- itemResponse (array of objects)
- additionalAttributes (object)
- totalItems (integer)
- nextCursor (string)

In my case I have over 2000 items in the catalog, but by default it will just return 20 items with a nextCursor so I can retrieve the next items. Unfortunately, i'm not getting my nextCursor in the response. I tried contacting walmart and been waiting for a reply over 2 weeks, but never got a single reply.

This is what my response looks like:
[image]

Is there anybody running into the same issue as me? I really don't know what to do in order to retrieve the nextCursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walmart's documentation is unclear, and contradictory.  They could use some good examples.  I was having the same problems as you were.

What worked for me was explicitly passing `nextCursor=*` for the first page.

I know the documentation says that's the default, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

The response will have the nextCursor value for the next page.